# React Native OpenCV Face Recognition

Tags: reactjs, react-native, opencv

I was already finished with the creation of a native module for the latest OpenCV for Android.

However, I am trying to access the `haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml` file using the file directory format below but it cannot be loaded.

Has anyone tried to create a react native module for OpenCV and was able to create face recognition using Java in React Native?

I am expecting to create a function in react native using OpenCV java that will have 2 base64 inputs and then do face matching then face recognition.

```
@ReactMethod
public void faceRecognition(String referenceBase64, String capturedBase64, Callback errorCallback, Callback successCallback) {
    try {
        
        //######## REGION FOR IMAGE CONVERTION ########
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inDither = true;
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

                //reference base64 image convertion
                byte[] decodedString_reference = Base64.decode(referenceBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap image_reference = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString_reference, 0, decodedString_reference.length);

                //captured base64 image convertion
                byte[] decodedString_captured = Base64.decode(capturedBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap image_captured = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString_captured, 0, decodedString_captured.length);

        
        //######## REGION FOR FACE DETECTION ########
                String response = "";
                String filenameFaceCascade = "D://React-Native//FaceRecognition_v2//android//app//src//main//java/com//reactlibrary//haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml";
                CascadeClassifier classifier = new CascadeClassifier();

                if (!classifier.load(filenameFaceCascade)) 
                {       
                    response = "Error"; //this is being returned for the success callback. The plan is that it should return a response of "Test_only"
                }

                else 
                {  
                    response = "Test_only";
                }
        
        successCallback.invoke(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        errorCallback.invoke(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Used forward slash.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @toyotaSupra  thank you for the response. I tried to change the path using forward slash but still cannot load the .xml file. Here is the code. I edited my post to include the code I used.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to load the haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml file using an absolute file path which might not be valid on an Android device. In Android, you should use the getAssets() method to access files in the assets folder of your project.

To load the haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml file from the assets folder, you can use the following code snippet:

```
String filenameFaceCascade = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml";
InputStream is = getCurrentActivity().getAssets().open(filenameFaceCascade);
File cascadeDir = getCurrentActivity().getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File cascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir, filenameFaceCascade);
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(cascadeFile);

byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
is.close();
os.close();

CascadeClassifier classifier = new CascadeClassifier(cascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());
```